# How to add a picture inside a dialog box

Tags: dialog-window

I looked around the documentation, but didn't found anything that could help me add a picture in a dialogbox. I actually didn't know what should I have been looking for. Furthermore, if it is possible to add pictures in dialog boxes, I suspect that I should use a path file to that image, but I wish to use my mathematica program in any pc, so how can I have that image in my dialog box, regardless of where I use the code.
Thank you

Comment: Meanwhile, I found out that I might use the Import function but I still have the problem of using the image in any pc

Comment: `ico = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Clock"}], Scaled[{1/8, 1/8}]]; CreateDialog[{ico, TextCell["Enter a name: "], InputField[Dynamic[nm], String], DefaultButton[DialogReturn[ret = nm]]}];` gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0KC6.png). If you're asking about how to store an imported image in *Mathematica* for later use, that's a different question altogether.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What is the difference between using the code you have shown and importing the image? If i import the image in mathematica for later use (which I think is what I want if I want to use my code in other devices) do I still have to specify the path file?

Comment: [Direct embedding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0EsJ.png) ought to work.

Comment: You mean directly "copy and paste" the image in the notebook? If yes, it worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "dialog box" is just another notebook.  It can contain and display anything that can be displayed in a notebook.

When you `Import` an image, you get a little picture as the output.  Just use this as-is.  Do you already know how to show text in a dialog?  Just copy and paste this image in place of that text in your code.